# Apache Cassandra 3.0.0 Materialized View: can the view's partition key change due to changes to the underlying table?

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

Just thinking about this so please correct my understanding if any of this isn't right.

Environment: Apache Cassandra v3.0.0

Say you have a table and a materialized view created on it:

```
create table source(
id text, field text, stamp timestamp, data text, 
primary key(id, field))

create materialized view myview as
select * from source
where data is not null and id is not null and field is not null
primary key (data, field, id)
```

My understanding is that `myview.data` would essentially be the partition key for the view here (and data in `source` is automatically replicated by the server into `myview`?).

**If that is true, what happens internally when a table update is performed on `source` table and the `source.data` column is updated?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this to Cassandra's user mailing list and got the following two useful replies that answered the question.

It should all just work as expected, as if by magic. That's the whole point of having MV, so that Cassandra does all the bookkeeping for you. Yes, the partition key can change, so an update to the base table can cause one (or more) MV rows to be deleted and one (or more) new MV rows to be created. It does not change the partition key per se, but it is as if it were changed and the row moved. **This can in fact result in the row moving from one node to another if the column(s) used in the MV partition key change in the base table row.**

-- Jack Krupansky

In the case of an update to the source table where data is changed, a tombstone will be generated for the old value and an insert will be generated for the new value. This happens serially for the source partition, so if there are multiple updates to the same partition, a tombstone will be generated for each intermediate value.

This blog post has more details: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views

-Carl Yeksigian